# if a JAR is placed on app servers's classpath how do we reference it from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts

On our application we are getting an error saying:

```
PWC6117: File "/struts-tags" not found
```

code in the file thats giving error is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

This file is in struts2-core.jar which is placed on the classpath of the app server (Sun 9.1).

The code will work fine and not complain when the jar is actually in WEB-INF/lib of the application, compared to being on classpath of the appserver. But we can not change that. it has to be on appservers classpath.

But how should we change our code so that this error goes away?

I can create mapping in my web.xml so that tag uri's are change. but what should taglib-location be changed to? so that it references to app servers classpath?

```
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld</taglib-uri> 
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld</taglib-location> 
</taglib>
```

Comment: it think the app servers' classpath would be a really strange place for this jar; since you might want to deploy different apps on it with different versions of struts...

What can you actually place in the classpath of the webapplication; can you perhaps write in the classes folder?

Comment: we are in a 'controlled' environment. lots of apps are deployed by a group. group decided it was best to put struts2 core on app server since everyone uses it. I can play anything on classpath of application as long as it is not already on classpath of app server.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the app server, and the web application itself are running two different classloaders. So make sure that the jar file is available not just in the app server's classpath, but in the classpath of the application itself. If there is a "shared" lib directory (thats where it would be in WebSphere... not sure about Sun) put it there

Comment: yes, its in the shared lib. thats why the Java code does not complain even though it is importing struts2 classes. Only JSP tags are complaining.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP standard does not require an app server to use **classpath** to locate/load tag librariy **tld** files.  This is just an option available for app servers to store common TLDs.  However, the container will use the classpath to locate the **class** files associated with the tag library.  But as a starting step, it must first locate and load the **tld** file; for this purpose, pretend the classpath doesn't exist.

According to the JSP 2.2 standard, a JSP container maps the URI used in the taglib directive into a Tag Library Descriptor in two steps:

1. It resolves the **URI** into a **TLD resource [URL] path** (a context relative URL path, starting with "/", without protocol or host - i.e. relative to the base URL of the webapp).

   This mapping occurs though a **taglib map**, built from (in order of priority):

   - A) Java EE platform tag library mappings (JSP Tag Library & JSF libraries)
   - B) Taglib Map in web.xml
   - C) Implicit Map Entries from TLDs in WEB-INF/lib/*.jar, WEB-INF/*.tld & WEB-INF/**/*.tld
   - D) Implicit Map Entries from the Container
   - E) A fallback, targetted to casual development use, where URI is interpreted as a direct path to the TLD.

   Here B) or D) could be useful to you.  But D) is an optional priority extension mechanism available to the container, where it inserts mappings of taglibs that the container implements/provides.  Reading SUN 9.1 doc, it seems it does not provide D).  So, if SUN 9.1 does not detect TLDs in JARs on you classpath, **you should use B)**, as you've started to do in your Q.
2. It derives the TLD object from the TLD resource path.
   The TLD resource path should resolve to:

   - a TLD file directly,
   - or to a JAR file that has a TLD file at location META-INF/taglib.tld.

   If the TLD resource path is not one of these two cases, a fatal translation error will occur.

   Neither of these currently apply to you.  So, according to the standard, you either need to **extract the jar contents and point `<taglib-location>` to the resulting TLD file**, OR you should **insert `META-INF/taglib.tld` into the JAR file** on your class path and **point `<taglib-location>` to the JAR file**.

Comment: So. Does this mean that a .tld file cannot, in practice, be referenced from classpath?

Comment: An app server is not required to allow a tld to be referenced from classpath.  If it does allow it, then that's an optional extension beyond the standard.  It must allow the tld to be referenced as a tld resource path though, relative to the webapp.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. So, do application servers actually have such extensions?

Comment: The main ones don't.  E.g. Tomcat (http://www.tomcatexpert.com/knowledge-base/best-practice-implementing-custom-tag-libraries), Weblogic (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13722/admin.htm#i361416), Websphere (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp).  A quick glance at Sun seems no.

Comment: Thanks. I'll award the bounty when the system lets me to (4 hours till time constraint expires).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've already gotten yourself familiar with how TLDs work when placed inside `WEB-INF` and how the container builds a map to match the `uri` attributes of JSP `taglib` directives. So, I'll be more focussed on your `classpath` problem here.

#### As per the JSP 2.0 spec

A container looks for TLD files in the following four locations *only*

- /WEB-INF/MyTags.tld
- /WEB-INF/Any-Sub-Dir/MyTags.tld
- /WEB-INF/lib/tag-lib.jar with /META-INF/MyTags.tld
- /WEB-INF/lib/tag-lib.jar with /META-INF/Any-Sub-Dir/MyTags.tld

To not break pre-JSP 2.0 web applications the latest containers would still honour any `<taglib>` mappings found in `web.xml`. But, it doesn't help you in any way because the `<taglib-location>` still remains bound by the locations outlined above. I'm yet to come across any popular container that allows `.tld`s to be loaded from outside an application's `/WEB-INF`.

#### Answer

But, the constraint only applies to the tag library descriptors. The actual tag implementation class just needs to be in the `classpath`. Usually, the tag classes (along with the `tld`) are packed within the jar (like `struts2-core.jar`) and dropped in `WEB-INF/lib`.

But, they could very well be separate: inside `WEB-INF/classes`; or, some other jar in `WEB-INF/lib` or the application server's *shared library* itself. So, all you need to do is:

- Extract just the `/META-INF/struts-tags.tld` from your `struts2-core.jar`
- Place the `struts-tags.tld` inside `/WEB-INF` (`/tlds` or `/struts` etc.)
- Remove the `<taglib>` mapping (if running on a JSP 2.0 compliant container)

Some, prefer to keep the mappings just to record the locations of all the `tld` files being loaded. You could, alternatively, just bundle the `/META-INF/struts-tags.tld` in a `struts2-core-tags.jar` and drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: I'm not sure about OP, but I placed the bounty for the specific problem of not finding a way to have a *tld file* in the classpath. I am aware that tag classes themselves can be there.